# How to multiply 2 numbers form select options and sum the result

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form field with 2 select options for my services (logo design and letterhead design) where I want users to select the number of either logo or letter head designs they want or both.

For instance, they can select 2 logo design and 3 letter head designs. There is a fixed amount for both designs. All I want is for them to select the number they want and they can preview the total amount for all before they make payment.

I have my forms done and I can also see the amount for each select option but I'm stuck at calculating both services together.

I'm not too good at javascript but I understand a little.

```js
//Calculate branding amount by selected option
function logo(val) {
  var logo = val * 20000;
  document.getElementById("ansval").value = logo;
  var letterhead = vall * 20000;
  document.getElementById("ansval").value = letterhead;
  document.getElementById("ansval").value = logo + letterhead;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="logonumber">Number of logos required</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="logonumber" onChange="logo(this.value)">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="letterheads">Number of letterheads required</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="letterheads" onChange="logo(this.value)">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="ansval" id="ansval" disabled>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Pay</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work it would be better to have your function read both the selected values from the DOM, instead of passing in a single value and then trying to figure out what the other one should be. Then you can perform the calculation quite simply and update the `#ansval` element with the outcome.

Note the use of `parseInt()` in the below example so that the values are treated as numbers to be added instead of string to be concatenated. Also note the use of unobtrusive event bindings. Using `onchange` and other inline event attributes is bad practice and should be avoided where possible.

With all that said, try this:

```js
let logoEl = document.querySelector('#logonumber');
let letterheadEl = document.querySelector('#letterheads');

logoEl.addEventListener('change', calcTotal);
letterheadEl.addEventListener('change', calcTotal);

function calcTotal() {
  var numLogo = (parseInt(logoEl.value, 10) || 0) * 20000;
  var numLetterHead = (parseInt(letterheadEl.value, 10) || 0) * 20000;
  document.querySelector("#ansval").value = numLogo + numLetterHead;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="logonumber">Number of logos required</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="logonumber">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="letterheads">Number of letterheads required</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="letterheads">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="ansval" id="ansval" disabled>
</div>
<p></p>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Pay</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function have to take both the submitted value for proper calculation. i just modified your code a little bit and it's done.

```js
function logo(val)
        {
  
  var logo = document.getElementById("logonumber").value;
        var letterhead = document.getElementById("letterheads").value;  
        document.getElementById("ansval").value = (logo * 20000) + (letterhead * 20000);

        }
```

```html
   <div class="form-group">
   
    <label for="logonumber">Number of logos required</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="logonumber" onChange="logo(this.value)">
      <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>


    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="letterheads">Number of letterheads required</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="letterheads" onChange="logo(this.value)">
      <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="ansval" id="ansval" disabled>
  </div>
    <p></p>                             
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Pay</button>
</form>
```